# UITableView jumping on scrollToRow?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing issue with `UITableView` in Swift. Table contains lyrics. Each cell is a lyric class. I know which index I have to focus on so I show the current lyric in red and the rest in black.

All okay so far. But when using `scrollToRow`, it's working well before table starts to scroll down to lyrics outside the view. Once the `UITableView` starts scrolling outside the view, it starts jumping.

Any idea how to make it scroll smoothly to the current cell without jumping?

Here is how I make the table go to the desired lyric:

```
let lcCell = IndexPath(row: (vc_lyrics.sharedInstance().lyric_time[seconds]?.index)!, section: 0)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    vc_lyrics.sharedInstance().tableView.scrollToRow(at: lcCell, at: .none , animated: false)
    vc_lyrics.sharedInstance().tableView!.reloadData()
}
```

Or if I can keep the lyric cell in the center by scrolling the scrollview of the table, not its delegate `scrollToRow`.

Comment: Do not call `reloadData` immediately after calling `scrollToRow`. That is causing the scrolling issue.

Comment: @maddy thanks , but its lyrics sync table i need to reload the table data to change the lyrics colors in x seconds

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to set `animated` to `true`:

```
vc_lyrics.sharedInstance().tableView.scrollToRow(at: lcCell, at: .none , animated: true)
```

This will cause the cells to scroll smoothly. I would also think about whether or not you need to reload the `tableView` data here because that can also cause scrolling issues as [@rmaddy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982962/uitableview-jumping-on-scrolltorow#comment78927345_45982962).